# Django form error "this field is required" after HTMX request

Tags: python, django, python-requests, django-forms, htmx

I'm using HTMX lib to send the requests with Django. The issue is that after succeed htmx request with `project_form` swapped `project_detail_form` comes with "this field is required". What am I doing wrong?

This is my views.py:

```
def index(request):
    """Index view."""
    project_form = ProjectForm(data=request.POST or None)
    project_detail_form = ProjectDetailForm(data=request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            if project_form.is_valid():
                project_form.save()
                return render(
                    request,
                    "monitor/_project_detail_form.html",
                    context={"project_detail_form": project_detail_form},
                )
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse(f"Error: {e}")
    return render(request, "monitor/index.html", context={"project_form": project_form})
```

A part of index.html

```
            <form class="pt-4" hx-post="/" hx-target="this" hx-swap="innerHTML" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ project_form.as_div }}
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
            </form>
```

_project_detail_form.html

```
{% csrf_token %}
{{ project_detail_form.as_div }}
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
```

forms.py

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Project form."""

    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}))
    check_interval = forms.IntegerField(
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"})
    )
    is_active = forms.BooleanField(
        required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={"class": "form-check"})
    )

    class Meta:
        """Meta."""

        model = Project
        fields = "__all__"


class ProjectDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Project Detail form."""

    project = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Project.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-select"}),
    )
    url = forms.URLField(widget=forms.URLInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}))
    pagination = forms.IntegerField(
        required=False, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"})
    )
    is_active = forms.BooleanField(
        required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={"class": "form-check"})
    )

    class Meta:
        """Meta."""

        model = ProjectDetail
        fields = ["project", "url", "pagination", "is_active"]
```

[image: live demo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `project_form`'s `request.POST` for `project_detail_form`. Django thinks that you have already submitted the details form as well.

```
def index(request):
    """Index view."""
    project_form = ProjectForm(data=request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            if project_form.is_valid():
                project_form.save()
                return render(
                    request,
                    "monitor/_project_detail_form.html",
                    context={"project_detail_form": ProjectDetailForm()},
                )
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse(f"Error: {e}")
    return render(request, "monitor/index.html", context={"project_form": project_form})
```